# Find the coordinates of the Frame/Axes in the final display area of a plot

Tags: graphics, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica, plot

If I do a Plot with Frame->True is there a way I can find the coordinates of the corners of the Frame in the absolute coordinates of the image?  I have the numerical values of PlotRange and PlotRangePadding but note that I don't want to tamper with the actual plot in any way, just find out where in the full display area Mathematica chooses to place the frame/axes of the plot.

As pointed out by Brett Champion, I'm looking for the coordinates {x,y} such that Scaled[{0,0}] == ImageScaled[{x,y}].

[Note that I edited this question to remove my confusing misuse of the term "scaled coordinates".]

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone, especially Brett! I appended a function, geom, to Brett's answer that does exactly what I want, using his Rasterize trick (which I never would've thought of!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The corners of the frame are at `Scaled[{0,0}]` and `Scaled[{1,1}]`.

The corners of the full graphic (including labels) are at `ImageScaled[{0,0}]` and `ImageScaled[{1,1}]`.

Converting between them is hard, although in theory it's possible to convert `Scaled` and user (unscaled) coordinates if you know the actual, numeric, settings for `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`.

Depending on your application, you might also be able to use MousePosition, which knows these things as well.

`Rasterize` (and HTML export) also know how to find bounding boxes of annotations, in a bitmap/pixel coordinate system:

```
In[33]:= Rasterize[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  Prolog -> {LightYellow, 
    Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], "One", 
     "Region"]}], "Regions"]

Out[33]= {{"One", "Region"} -> {{22., 1.33573}, {358.9, 209.551}}}
```

Here's how dreeves used that Rasterize trick to make a function to return exactly what he was looking for (note the assumption of a global variable `imgsz` which gives the ImageSize option for rasterizing the plot -- the coordinates of the frame depend on that value):

```
(* Returns the geometry of the frame of the plot: 
   {width, height, x offset, y offset, total width, total height}. *)
geom[p_Graphics] := Module[{q, x1, y1, x2, y2, xmax, ymax},
  q = Show[p, Prolog->{Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}], Scaled[{1,1}]], 
                                  "MAGIC00","MAGIC11"]}];
  {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}} = Rasterize[q, "Regions", ImageSize->imgsz][[1,2]];
  {xmax,ymax} = Rasterize[p, "RasterSize", ImageSize->imgsz];
  {x2-x1, y2-y1, x1, y1, xmax, ymax}]
```

Comment: Ah, this is helpful!  Converting Scaled[{0,0}] and Scaled[{1,1}] to ImageScaled is what I'm after. Ie, what is the (x,y) such that Scaled[{0,0}] == ImageScaled[{x,y}].  I do know the settings PlotRange and PlotRangePadding. I guess I'll add that to the question. Thanks again, Brett!

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't see your addendum when I wrote my comment. So that Annotation trick seems to be generating exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: You should be able to do that with a couple of calls to Rasterize, then. Once with "Regions", and once with "RasterSize".

Comment: I like that this also works without modifying the plot (call it `p`):  `Rasterize[
 Show[p, Prolog -> {Annotation[
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], "One", 
     "Region"]}], "Regions"]`

Answer (score 5):

The coordinates of the upper left corner of the frame are always `Scaled[{0,1}]`.
The coordinates of the lower right corner of the frame are always `Scaled[{1,0}]`.

Let's place large points at the upper left and lower right corners:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[.08], Point[Scaled[{0, 1}]], Point[Scaled[{1, 0}]]} ]
```

When I click on the graph (see below) , it is obvious that there is no padding around the frame of the plot.

[image: no padding]

Now, with `ImagePadding` on,  let's place `Point`s in the same corners:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,  
ImagePadding -> {{37, 15}, {20, 48}}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[.08], Point[Scaled[{0, 1}]],  Point[Scaled[{1, 0}]]} ]
```

The `Point`s stay at the corners of the graph frame.
There is  `ImagePadding` around the graph frame.

[image: with padding]

EDIT: Based on the clarification of the question by dreeves.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 1, 9}, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, 
Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 30, 
FrameTicks -> {Range[9], Automatic}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[.08], Point[Scaled[{0, 1}]], Point[Scaled[{1, 0}]]}]
```

[image: Frameticks]

I've drawn the plot as 300x300 to simplify the numbers. 
Here's the analysis.

1. [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html) states that `ImagePadding` "is defined within ImageSize".
2. The image shown above has a width and height of 300 pixels.
3. There is a 30 pixel margin drawn around the frame; this corresponds to 10% of the width and height.
4. So the  frame corners should be, starting from the origin, at `ImageScaled[{.1,.1}]`, `ImageScaled[{.9,.1}`, `ImageScaled[{.9,.9}]` & `ImageScaled[{.1,.9}]`.

It's easy to work out the value for other `AspectRatio`s and `ImageSize`s.

Comment: Yeah, I probably mean something like "absolute coordinates in the full display area". Do you know the right terminology? I'll update the question (or feel free to!).

Comment: Oh, but if scaled coordinates have (0,0) at one corner of the full display area and (1,1) at the other corner, then scaled coordinates would indeed tell me what I want to know, namely where are the corners of the actual frame?

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I just edited the question to be clearer about what I'm really after: what are the coordinates of those black dots in ImageScaled coordinates, where {0,0} is the corner of the whole display area, not just the frame?

Comment: @dreeves  I attempted to show how to describe the corners of the frame according to their location in the full image space.

Comment: I think the problem now is that I can't hardcode ImagePadding. That's the problem I had with Mr.Wizard's answer. It's looking like this is going to take something like Brett Champion's Rasterize trick. Thanks again for the help with this!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to take manual control of ImagePadding:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 5}, {20, 5}}]
```

[image]

```
ImageTake[Rasterize[%], {5, -20}, {30, -5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that cuts off the text if it's too wide.  Try plotting Sin[x]+10^6 in your example.  Good approach but that glitch is a dealbreaker for what I'm after.

Comment: @dreeves yes, but of course you could use different values.  I also don't know if this addresses your scaling concern.

Comment: Well, I don't want to mess with the original plot, just find out the coordinates of the frame edges, wherever mma decides to put them.

Comment: @dreeves you may be able to extract useful information from `FullGraphics` but that loses aspect ratio, and at the moment I cannot recall how to fix that; it's somewhere in the MathGroup archive.  ps forgot to upvote your question; fixed!